# org.apache.kylin.rest.service.QueryService.doQueryWithCache(QueryService.java:424)

Tags: kylin

Kirin multi-band parameter query error.

post:
  {
    "sql": "SELECT        loan.create_time AS time_date,        loan.apply_orders AS apply_orders,        lend.loan_orders AS loan_orders,        round(        cast(applyLend.apply_and_loan_orders AS DOUBLE) / loan.apply_orders,4        ) AS loan_pass_rate        FROM        (        SELECT        create_time,        count(borrow_id) AS apply_orders        FROM        APP_BI_ORDER_APPLY         WHERE create_time=?         GROUP BY        create_time        ) loan        LEFT JOIN (        SELECT        LOAN_TIME,        count(borrow_id) AS loan_orders        FROM        APP_BI_ORDER_APPLY         WHERE LOAN_TIME=?         GROUP BY        LOAN_TIME        ) lend ON lend.LOAN_TIME = loan.create_time        LEFT JOIN (        SELECT        LOAN_TIME,        count(borrow_id) AS apply_and_loan_orders        FROM        APP_BI_ORDER_APPLY         WHERE LOAN_TIME=? AND  create_time=?         GROUP BY        LOAN_TIME        ) applyLend ON applyLend.LOAN_TIME = loan.create_time",
    "project": "BI",
    "acceptPartial": false,
    "backdoorToggles": {
        "ATTR_STATEMENT_MAX_ROWS": "0"
    },
    "params": [
        {
            "className": "java.lang.String",
            "value": "2018-06-01"
        },
        {
            "className": "java.lang.String",
            "value": "2018-06-01"
        },
        {
            "className": "java.lang.String",
            "value": "2018-06-01"
        },
        {
            "className": "java.lang.String",
            "value": "2018-06-01"
        }
    ]
}

error message:
   {
    "code": "999",
    "data": null,
    "msg": "Unknown error.",
    "stacktrace": "org.apache.kylin.rest.exception.InternalErrorException: Unknown error.\n\tat org.apache.kylin.rest.service.QueryService.doQueryWithCache(QueryService.java:424)\n\tat org.apache.kylin.rest.service.QueryService.doQueryWithCache(QueryService.java:351)\n\tat org.apache.kylin.rest.controller.QueryController.query(QueryController.java:86)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:209)\n\tat com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:244)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n",
    "exception": "Unknown error.",
    "url": "http://ip/kylin/api/query"
}

Answer (score 0):

This has been recorded as a JIRA, please check there: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KYLIN-3629